# How fast does water need to travel to not boil

Tags: thermodynamics

I am considering placing a 60 foot coil of 1/2 inch copper tubing, laying flat, on the top of wood fired burn chamber made of metal.  The top of the metal chamber reaches 700 plus degrees when fired well.  How fast does the water need to travel through the tubing in order not to boil before it exits the tube?  What if I change the size of the copper tube or the length of the tube?  The purpose of placing the tubing on the burn chamber is to make a hydronic heat exchanger.

Comment: This seems like a physics question to me. I don't see how one would think this is a homework question, either given the setup or the obvious problem in the question. I'd like to answer it, please reopen it.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz It's more of an engineering question than a physics one.  Still off topic here.  This is also missing a lot of detail to give adequate answers.

Comment: @JMac - the difference between heat and temperature is most definitely physics. And the missing detail is precisely what I will use to introduce those physics concepts.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz The difference between heat and temperature definitely is physics, no one is arguing that.  That's not what the question is asking.  The question is quite specifically looking for the required flow rate for this specific scenario.  Those types of questions are not on topic here.  There's also more than one missing detail here.

Comment: @JMac - The OP is asking a non-sequitur, which is what I would like to explain.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I'm not sure I follow.  Determining the temperature of the water based on the temperature at the source is a legitimate question.  It would just require more information from the OP on how this is set up; but because solving that is not on topic here, it was closed.  If more material and geometry information were given; this would look like a fairly standard question in a heat transfer textbook.

Comment: @JMac - you can calculate the amount of water that will boil based solely on a single temperature? So the amount that would boil above a match at 700 degrees would be the same as this much larger fire at 700? That's fascinating!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz No; that's why I said we need to know the materials and geometry if we wanted to give estimates.  If we knew the size of the surfaces and approximate maximum or average temperatures of the heating surface, you could come up with a flow rate to ensure it never boils.  Either way, such questions aren't on topic here.  Whatever answer you provide would either be off topic (as the question is) or wouldn't actually answer what is asked.

Comment: @JMac - I think I can make a fabulous answer that will be on-topic and answer the OP, and be great reading for the next person too.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz The question is quite explicitly asking for the fluid velocity through the tube.  That is off topic.  Anything you put as an answer would be answering an off-topic question; which is bad form here.  If you didn't provide an actual flowrate (which you can't with the information given) then it would be "not an answer" because you don't answer the question asked.  If you really want to answer a conceptual question that you think is relevant, you can always ask a new question and self answer it; but I don't know if it would be well received.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss whether this question is a good fit for [physics.se], let's have that discussion in [chat] or on [meta]. I personally think it's on the boundary between a homework-like question and an engineering question, but we have a [reopen process](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) for just this reason.

Comment: Both of you are right, it is a physics question and an engineering question.  Physics of the heat transfer/flow rate must be established before the engineering.  The volume of the 1/2 inch copper tubing is 0.00151 cubic feet per linear ft, and holds 0.0113 gallons of water per linear ft.  The wall thickness of the tubing is 0.049 inches.  The burner's surface the tubing rest on is square 22 inches wide and 3/16 inches thick.  The temp of the water entering the tube would be 75 F with 0 pressure.  Hopefully this additional information will assist you in analyzing the question about flow rate.

Comment: @rob - I looked for you in Physics Chat, but you were not there. Looking around the SO system, I could not find any way to "open" such a chat with you. My reasons for reopening should be clear from the thread above, but for clarity: this question is a non-sequitur. I intend to explain the physics of heat and how that can be used to calculate the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz There's no need to wait for me to appear in chat personally; if you link to this question and politely start a conversation then you'll get feedback from whoever is in there. When I wrote "let's have that discussion" I meant as a community, not you and I individually. Sorry for the confusion.